# Maven jars classes conflicts

Tags: maven

1. We are using maven in our project, we are facing some issue with
   jars

   Issue is :

   We have `ss_css2` jar and `cssparser` jar in project. Those two are being
   used in different functionality.

   The problem is those two jars have same class with same package

   `com.steadystate.css.parser.CSSOMParser`

Because of that we are getting conflicts. The place where it actually
needs to get `CSSOMParser` class from cssparser instead it is
    resolving class in `ss_css2` jar because of that am getting below
    exception

```
com.steadystate.css.parser.CSSOMParser.<init>(Lorg/w3c/css/sac/Parser;)V
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
com.steadystate.css.parser.CSSOMParser.<init>(Lorg/w3c/css/sac/Parser;)V
    at
com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.host.css.CSSStyleSheet.parseCSS(CSSStyleSheet.java:882)
    at
com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.host.css.CSSStyleSheet.<init>(CSSStyleSheet.java:193)
    at
com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.host.css.CSSStyleSheet.loadStylesheet(CSSStyleSheet.java:341)
    at
com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.host.html.HTMLLinkElement.getSheet(HTMLLinkElement.java:152)
    at
com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.host.css.StyleSheetList.item(StyleSheetList.java:167)
    at
com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.host.Window.getComputedStyle(Window.java:1687)
    at
com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.DomNode.isDisplayed(DomNode.java:749)
    at
com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlElement.isDisplayed(HtmlElement.java:1319)
    at
org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitWebElement.isDisplayed(HtmlUnitWebElement.java:490)
    at org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitWebElement$1.call(
```

If we remove that ss_css2 jar other functionality getting failed,
    getting below exception while doing text to pdf convertion

```
ERROR core.JobRunShell:211 - Job
com.scraper.ScheduledAgentLauncher.ScheduledAgent_DMSAgentProcessor_8
threw an unhandled Exception: 
org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.JobMethodInvocationFailedException:
Invocation of method 'run' on target class [class
com.highradius.dms.scheduler.DMSAgentScheduledAction] failed; nested
exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
com/steadystate/css/parser/SACParser    at
org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.MethodInvokingJobDetailFactoryBean$MethodInvokingJob.executeInternal(MethodInvokingJobDetailFactoryBean.java:273)
    at
org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.QuartzJobBean.execute(QuartzJobBean.java:86)
    at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:202)    at
org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:529)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
com/steadystate/css/parser/SACParser    at
org.zefer.html.doc.css.d.<init>(Unknown Source)     at
org.zefer.html.doc.css.c.<init>(Unknown Source)     at
org.zefer.html.doc.css.c.<init>(Unknown Source)
```

Please suggest what is the best approach to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

you may use maven-dependency-plugin and configure the include/exclude  parameters to include or exclude classes.

See [Unpacking specific artifacts](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/examples/unpacking-artifacts.html)

hope this helps.